# What type is error returned from gRPC call in Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

For example we have below sample of code on the server side:

```
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.InvalidArgument, "request missing required field: Name")
}
```

On the caller side we have the next lines of code:

```
r, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: reqName})
if err != nil {
    if status.Code(err) == codes.InvalidArgument {
        return
    }
}
```

`c.SayHello` is a `RPC` call which returned an `error` which somehow under the hood was casted to a `type grpcstatus interface{ GRPCStatus() *Status }`
so all the underlying metadata was preserved during the `RPC` call.

How does `proto` preserve all information about actual returned error and what interfaces the error is implementing?

How does client know that the returned error implements `type grpcstatus interface{ GRPCStatus() *Status }`?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/status